# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

Tags: raspbian, python, opencv

I installed openCV on my pi following this install guide https://www.murtazahassan.com/opencv-raspberry-pi-installation/

My goal is to use facial recognition however I am having no luck getting it to work.

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

which throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

I also ran the following command to install opencv-contrib-python:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python==4.1.1.26
```

also, no luck unless there is something else I need to run to get it to work?

Please be aware I am new to the python and raspberry community.

Comment: Can you import OpenCV using `import cv2`? This problem has appeared on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), see if this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655699/attributeerror-module-cv2-face-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer) helps as well. It is probably worth me adding that this is not necessarily on topic here as it is a coding question not necessarily specific to the Pi.

Comment: Yes I am importing cv2.

Comment: What is the problem? Installing OpenCV? Does it install without error? The first line of the commands from the tutorial you used,  noted to install **rpi-update**. Only that is very error prone. You should not use it, except you are knowing what you do and advised by a developer.

Comment: I totally did not use that line, It does install correctly it just won't let me use the cv2.face class :(